# How to convert a CSV into columns of a single row?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a comma separated variable like

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

and I want all those variables as columns of a single row

like

```
a|b|c|d|e --------
```

more examples

```
MISC FEES,UNIV EXE,ID FEE,TENT FEE,CAU FEES,GYM FEE
```

this is the comma separated variable I have and using SQL I need to convert it into columns

```
MISCFEES UNIVEXE IDFEE TENTFEE CAUFEES GYMFEE
```

as column values of a single row where misc fees is first column, univfee is next column and so on

Comment: What programming language do you want to use?

Comment: sql or tsql without temporary tables

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have the inbuilt functionality for adding comma seperated values to seperate columns in single row. You have to build that using either a function or stored procedure.

You can use [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to find position of each delimiter and then use [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to get hold of each value between commas and update your columns accordingly.

Comment: but i dont want to use a temp table.can it be done through select query

Comment: @Vivek - You will not need a temp table here, but you will need a stored procedure or a function. Store split values in variables and use it for columns. Using only one select query, its not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The below function will separate each value of a comma-separated list 
into columns and return a table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CommaDelimitedToTable]
    (
      @String AS varchar(MAX)
    )
RETURNS @RetTable Table ( DataValue varchar(500) )
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnedTable Table ( DataValue varchar(500) )
    DECLARE @BreakLoop Int
    DECLARE @CharIndex Int
    DECLARE @StringTmp Varchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @WrdTmp Varchar(500)
    DECLARE @Count Int
    SET @StringTmp = @String
    SET @Count = 0
    SET @BreakLoop = 0
    WHILE @BreakLoop = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @CharIndex = CHARINDEX(',', @StringTmp, 1)
            IF @CharIndex = 0 OR @CharIndex IS NULL
                BEGIN
                    SET @WrdTmp = Ltrim(Rtrim(@StringTmp))
                    SET @BreakLoop = 1
                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN

                    SET @WrdTmp = ltrim(rtrim(Left(@StringTmp, @CharIndex - 1)))

                    SET @StringTmp = Ltrim(rtrim(Right(@StringTmp,
                                                       Len(@StringTmp)
                                                       - Len(@WrdTmp) - 1)))
                END

            INSERT  INTO @ReturnedTable ( DataValue )
            VALUES  ( @WrdTmp )
            SET @WrdTmp = ''
            SET @Count = @Count + 1
            IF @BreakLoop = 1 
                BEGIN 
                    BREAK
                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    CONTINUE
                END
        END
    INSERT  INTO @RetTable
            SELECT  DataValue
            FROM    @ReturnedTable
    RETURN
   END
```

Comment: Actually, I just reread the answer, my response will create a table with each value as a row, not each value as a column.